# Launch process as another user/group (in init.d script)

Tags: process, init, privileges

I am editing a init.d script. The init.d script runs a utility script which then runs an process. From either bash scripts how would I make it launch the main process as a specific user and group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the su(1) command, it has an option that allows you to run a command via the user's shell, example:

```
su foo -c ls
```

This will switch to the user *foo* and run the ls command. If the user you want to use does not have a valid shell (ie it's not in /etc/shells, like /bin/false or /sbin/nologin) you will also have to specify a shell on the command line. Example with output:

```
# su nobody -s /bin/bash -c id
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Comment: su seems to not like that i give it many arguments. I get `Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]` and `su: unrecognized option '--debug'`

Comment: Its not exactly working. When i execute this line as root i get an error `su www-data -c ${MONOSERVER} /applications=${WEBAPPS} /socket=unix:/path/monoserve.pid &` if i `su www-data` set all the vars and run `${MONOSERVER} /applications=${WEBAPPS} /socket=unix:/path/monoserve.pid &` it works fine. How so i solve this?

Comment: @acidzombie24 `su` takes a single argument, which is a shell command. You need to write `su www-data -c '$MONOSERVER "/application=$WEBAPPS" "/socket=unix:/path/monoserve.pid"'`, and make sure that `MONOSERVER` and `WEBAPPS` are exported by the parent shell. (Note: do not do `su … -c "$MONOSERVER …"` as this will fail if any of the variables contain shell special characters.) And if you have a dedicated daemon launcher [such as `start-stop-daemon`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22107/launch-process-as-another-user-group-in-init-d-script/22109#22109), use it.

Comment: Gilles: Alright, i am not replacing the init.d script with that am i? I can put all the variables into a new script and launch that as it be easy and i wouldnt have to learn anything. But whats so special about start-stop-daemon? I'll leave a comment on that answer

Comment: Is it better to use su or su -login ? I read the man of su but I cannot understand for this specific case

Comment: This doesn't work, this needs the user password. Or If run via sudo, it breaks the command put between single quotes. command `sudo su myuser -c '/etc/init.d/myscript start'` result: `/etc/init.d/myscript: line 63:    75 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${PROG_BIN}`  (something inside my script which works very well if run outside sudo)

Answer (score 4):

If `start-stop-daemon` is available on your system you should probably use it and have a look at its options (especially `-u` and `-g` in this case).

(Otherwise, you might use a combination of `su` and `sg`.)

**Update:** Here is an example taken from some `/etc/init.d/mpd` script (which uses `start-stop-daemon`):

- Start command:

  ```
  echo "Starting Music Player Daemon"
  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --exec /usr/bin/mpd \
      --pidfile /var/run/mpd.pid --make-pidfile \
      -- --no-daemon /etc/mpd.conf 2>/dev/null
  ```

  Everything that follows `--` is an argument to the `/usr/bin/mpd` program itself. (The daemonization procedure is taken care of by the start-stop-daemon script so `mpd` is asked not to care about it with `--nodaemon`.)
- Stop command:

  ```
  echo "Stopping Music Player Daemon"
  start-stop-daemon --stop --exec /usr/bin/mpd --pidfile /var/run/mpd.pid
  ```

If `mpd` was not dropping privileges by itself, one would need to add (for example) `-u mpd`, `-g mpd` options to the `start-stop-daemon` command.

Comment: I am not replacing the init.d script with start-stop-daemon am i? wouldnt it be easier to use su and a script file? If i replace init.d how do i install it to run at startup? what am i passing to start-stop-daemon? -edit- i am googling examples ATM maybe i wont need an answer but i feel like its going to be a complex answer

Comment: No luck. Here is my line. It still runs as root. I checked the man pages and i still dont know what to do about this. `start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background -u www-data -g www-data --exec ${MONOSERVER} --pidfile /path/monoserve.pid --make-pidfile -- /applications=${WEBAPPS} /socket=unix:/path/monoserve.pid`